# Having 2 forms on the same page in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to tackle a "two forms on one page" issue with my PHP code, but its turning out to be more tirkcy than I expected, and just isn't behaving in the correct way as I thought it would.

For the first form (Login) I'm using this if statement to determine if the message if for the Login.

```
@if(Session::has('message') && Session::get('last_message_for') == 'login')
<div class="notification is-{{ Session::get('color') }}">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Session::get('message') }}
</div>
@elseif($errors->first() && Session::get('last_message_for') == 'login')
<div class="notification is-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $errors->first() }}
</div>
@endif
```

I've got the same code for my second form, but it just checks the `last_message_for` for a different value to 'login'.

```
@if(Session::has('message') && Session::get('last_message_for') == 'modal')
<div class="modal is-active" id="modal-forgotPassword">
@else 
<div class="modal" id="modal-forgotPassword">
@endif
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card">
        <header class="modal-card-head">
            <p class="modal-card-title" id="open-modal">Forgot Password?</p> <button class="delete"></button>
        </header>
        <form action="{{ route('frontend.guest.password.forgot') }}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <section class="modal-card-body">
                <div class="content">
                    @if(Session::has('message') && Session::get('last_message_for') == 'modal')
                    <div class="notification is-{{ Session::get('color') }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Session::get('message') }}
                    </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="field">
                        <p class="control has-icons-left">
                            <input class="input" name="email" placeholder="Enter an email..." type="email">
                            <span class="icon is-small is-left"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                </div>
            </section>
            <footer class="modal-card-foot">
                <button class="button is-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Send email</button>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now down to the issue, the Login part works perfectly fine and shows the error messages when there are any for it, but the second one isn't showing any errors when I have some.

I'm using this to set the last_message_for

```
Session::put('last_message_for', 'login');
```

Here is the code for my second form:

```
public function onForgotPassword(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,mail',
    ]);

    Session::put('last_message_for', 'modal');

    if ( $validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->route('frontend.guest.login')->withErrors($validator->messages());;
    }
    else {
        Mail::to($request->input('email'))->send(new ForgotPasswordEmail());
        return redirect()->route('frontend.guest.login')->withMessage('Email Sent')->withColor('warning');
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't see where you show error for second form like this `$errors->first()` you only have code for if seesion has `message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling validation errors, only the messages returned, this should do it.

```
@if(Session::has('message') && Session::get('last_message_for') == 'modal')
<div class="notification is-{{ Session::get('color') }}">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Session::get('message') }}
</div>
@elseif($errors->first() && Session::get('last_message_for') == 'login')
<div class="notification is-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $errors->first() }}
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: thnx for this, I never really noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

I have two forms in the same page so you can easily assign it error to each form using flash session 
in your controller just use session like this line

```
use Session;
```

this code related to two search forms

```
//searchInHistory
 public function searchInHistory(){
    $date = Request()->all();
    $rules   = [
        'dateFrom'   =>'required',
        'dateTo'     =>'required',
    ];

    $validator = Validator($date,$rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        Session::flash('inError', 'inError');
        return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }else{

        $store = DB::table('stores')->select(
            'store_details.id',
            'store_details.status',
            'stores.id AS storeId',
            'stores.partNo',
            'stores.title',
            'store_details.serialNo',
            'store_details.created_at',
            'store_details.updated_at'
            )
            ->join('store_details', 'store_details.storeId', '=', 'stores.id')
            ->where('store_details.status','inside')
            ->whereBetween('store_details.created_at',[$date['dateFrom'],$date['dateTo']])
            ->get();
        return view('crm.store.in',compact('store'));
    }
}
//===============
//searchHistory
 public function searchOutHistory(){
    $date = Request()->all();
    $rules   = [
        'dateFrom'   =>'required',
        'dateTo'     =>'required',
    ];

    $validator = Validator($date,$rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        Session::flash('inError', 'inError');
        return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }else{
        $store = DB::table('stores')->select(
            'store_details.id',
            'store_details.status',
            'stores.id AS storeId',
            'stores.partNo',
            'stores.title',
            'store_details.serialNo',
            'store_details.created_at',
            'store_details.updated_at'
            )
            ->join('store_details', 'store_details.storeId', '=', 'stores.id')
            ->where('store_details.status','outside')
            ->whereBetween('store_details.updated_at',[$date['dateFrom'],$date['dateTo']])
            ->get();
        return view('crm.store.out',compact('store'));
    }
}
//===============
```

the following code above each error assigned to  specific form using session 
this is blade code view code related to two form

```
  <!-- Main content -->
 <section class="content">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box">
          <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Store IN / OUT Control</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="box-body">
                    @if(session('outError'))
                        @if ($errors->any())
                          <div class="alert alert-danger">
                              <center>
                                  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                      {{ $error }}<br>
                                  @endforeach
                              </center>
                          </div>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                    @if(session('out'))
                        @if(session('save'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <center>
                               Products Came out of Successfully
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        @endif   
                    @endif

                       <!-- form start -->
                       <form role="form" method="post" action="{{url('admin/takeProductOutStore')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <div class="box-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$storeId}}">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Products in Store</label>
                                <select multiple class="form-control" name="products[]" required>
                                    @foreach($InDoorProducts as $row)
                                      <option value="{{$row->serialNo}}">{{$row->serialNo}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label>Date</label>
                                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <textarea class="textarea" required placeholder=" Write Notes"style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;" name="note" value="{{old('note')}}"></textarea>
                              </div>
                        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Out Store <b>&rarr;</b></button>
                          </div>
                       </form>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        @if(session('inError'))
                        @if ($errors->any())
                          <div class="alert alert-danger">
                              <center>
                                  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                      {{ $error }}<br>
                                  @endforeach
                              </center>
                          </div>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                    @if(session('in'))
                        @if(session('save'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <center>
                               Products Added to Store Again Successfully
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        @endif   
                    @endif

                    <!-- form start -->
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="{{url('admin/takeProductInStore')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      {{csrf_field()}}
                      <div class="box-body">
                          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$storeId}}">

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Products Out Store</label>
                              <select multiple class="form-control" name="products[]" required>
                                  @foreach($OutDoorProducts as $row)
                                    <option>{{$row->serialNo}}</option>
                                  @endforeach
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Date</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="textarea" required placeholder=" Write Notes"style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;" name="note" value="{{old('note')}}"></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div><!-- /.box-body -->

                      <div class="box-footer">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Back To Store <b>&larr;</b></button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          </section>
```